# virtualenv install linux error

Tags: linux, django, pip, virtualenv

I receive a funny error when trying to install virtualenv:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

yields the following error:

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 324, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py'
```

I was wondering if anybody had some insight as to  fixing this? I read that there may be reference in usr/bin to older versions of software, this is possible, but this computer is on the newer side. Is the best bet to go in and clear all references to 'virtualenv' (all that I can find that  is
)?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try sudo pip...? On the other hand, python is used extensively in Linux distributions. Can you use a python distribution like Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to install a package to a location that typically requires root privileges. You can do as @Vince West suggested and run `sudo pip install virtualenv`, or you can do `pip install --user virtualenv`, which will install packages to `~/.local/lib/python<version>/site-packages`. If you go that route, you'll likely want to make sure `$HOME/.local/bin` is included in your `$PATH`.